# Configuring maas-region-controller

Tags: maas, vagrant

When trying to install MAAS in a virtual machine, the following is displayed on the target's screen after running `sudo apt-get install maas`. The virtual machine is built by vagrant. Is there has any  incompatibility problem between MAAS and Vagrant?

[image]

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Comment: did you already have a psql installation?

Comment: Thank you! I have solved this problems, because I am in China, I have to add this: "sudo locale-gen zh_CN.UTF-8; sudo locale-gen"

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! I have solved this problems, because I am in China, I have to add this: "sudo locale-gen zh_CN.UTF-8; sudo locale-gen"